# Angular directive select2-blur event not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
angular.module('click-to-edit-select2', [])
.directive("clickToEditSelect2", function() {
  var editorTemplate = '<td id="4" class="click-to-edit-select2">' +
  '<div id="3" style="height:20px" ng-click="enableEditor()" ng-hide="view.editorEnabled">' +
  '{{value}} ' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div id="2" ng-show="view.editorEnabled" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 0px";>' +
  '<input id="1" type="hidden" ui-select2="select2Options" ng-model="view.editableValue" ng-change="changeText()" />' +
  '</div>' +
  '</td>';

  return {
      restrict: "A",
      replace: true,
      template: editorTemplate,
      scope: {
          value: "=clickToEditSelect2"
      },
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
          $scope.view = {
              //editableValue: $scope.term.TermId.id,
              editorEnabled: false
          };


          $scope.enableEditor = function() {
              if ($scope.$parent.term.Status == "new") {
                  $scope.view.editorEnabled = true;
                  $scope.view.editableValue = $scope.value;

              }
          };



          $scope.disableEditor = function() {
              $scope.view.editorEnabled = false;
          };

          $scope.save = function() {
              //alert($scope.term.TermId.id);
              $scope.value = $scope.view.editableValue.id;
              $scope.disableEditor();
          };

          $scope.$watch('view.editableValue', function(newVal, oldVal) {
              if (newVal != undefined && newVal != "") {
                  if (oldVal == newVal) return;
                  $element.addClass('valueChangedTD');
                  var str = newVal.text;
                  var res = str.split(" - ");
                  //slice the termID
                  res.splice(res.length - 1, 1);

                  var termDescription = res.join(' - ');

              }
          }, true);

          //select2 has its own blur event !
          $element.on('select2-blur', function(event) {
              $scope.save();
          });

          var initSelectionCb = function(item, callback) {
              if (item != "") {
                  var id = item.val();
                  var data = { id: id, text: id };
                  callback(data);
              }
          };

          $scope.select2Options = {
              placeholder: "Select Terminal",
              dropdownAutoWidth: 'true',
              multiple: false,
              width: "resolve",
              selectOnBlur: true,  //this does not seem to work
              initSelection: function(item, callback) {
                  //selects the initial item
                  initSelectionCb.call(self, item, callback);
              },
              ajax: {

                  url: "/GetDataSelect2",
                  type: "POST",
                  contentType: "application/json",
                  data: function(term, page) {

                      var Json = {};
                      Json.term = term;
                      Json.page = page;
                      Json.limit = 10;

                      return Json;

                  },
                  results: function(data, page) {
                      return { results: data.options };
                  }
              }
          }


      }
  };
```

});

Using select2 3.4.8
bootstrap 2.3.1
angular 1.2.19

As you can see I have set the onSelectBlur option (I have tried 'true' and true), but it doesn't work.

I added an event handler for the select2-blur event but it does not work as expected.

I expect to click the select2 ddl, select an option, then tab or click somewhere and have the div with the select2 hidden (which is what should happen when $scope.view.editorEnabled is set to false).

What is happening instead, is that after selecting an item from the ddl and then tabbing or clicking somewhere else the div with the select2 ddl is not hidden.  If I select an item the second time from the select2 ddl, then the div with the select2 ddl is hidden and the div with the selected value is shown.

I can see that the select2-blur event is being called every time (by setting breakpoint), but the divs do not update immediately . . . only when run twice.

I don't really want to attach the select2-blur event to the $element (which is the TD), but I'm at a loss for how to do this.  I've attempted to attach the event to various other elements I've found (.select2-choice, .select2-container) but I can't even get the events to fire.

At this point it's been a few hours, and I thought I could use a fresh pair of eyes.  It's probably something simple that I'm not seeing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a very simple $scope.$apply() here:

```
      //select2 has its own blur event !
      $element.on('select2-blur', function(event) {
          $scope.save();
          $scope.$apply();
      });
```

was the answer.  I suppose this has something to do with $scope values being changed within the callback of the event?